# Why I am getting error "cannot find symbol" when I would like to use java.io.File class?

Tags: java, class, cannot-find-symbol

I'd like to use `isDirectory()` method (java.io.File class). I created a simple test code to try out this method, however I always get a 'cannot find symbol' error.

My code:

```
import java.io.File;

public class MyUtils {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "/this/is/not/a/valid/path";
        boolean ValidPath = path.isDirectory();
        System.out.println(ValidPath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your `path` is a `String` object. You may instantiate a `File` object with the path `String`:

```
boolean ValidPath = new File(path).isDirectory();
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `path` is an instance type `String` and `isDirectory` is not a method available in the `String` class. To work with ***files*** or ***directories***, you have to use the appropriate [classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/).

Your code should look like this :

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class MyUtils {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "/this/is/not/a/valid/path";
        boolean isValidPath = Files.isDirectory(Paths.get(path));
        System.out.println(isValidPath);
    }
}
```

The `ValidPath` should be renamed to `isValidPath`.

As you want to check the validity of your path, you can use the method `exists` like this :

```
boolean isValidPath = Files.exists(Paths.get(path));
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because, isDirectory is a method of java.io.Files class, it must be called by a File object, but you are trying to invoke the method using a string object.

Create a File obj like: new File(path), the call isDirectory() method.